# How use Azure speech services (TTS) over than 1024 chars?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, bing, bing-speech, azure-speech

I'm using Azure Bing TTS for some math dictation. There is a lot of pauses between the number.

for instance:

```
Exercise number 1.
<prosody rate="default" contour="(80%,+20%) (90%,-50%)">
1
<break time="600ms" />
2
<break time="600ms" />
36
<break time="600ms" />
minus 5
</prosody>
.
```

it costs me a lot of `<break time="600ms" />`chars. I would like to overpass the 1024 char limit, but didn't found any way to overpass the 1024 char limit for the TSS service using REST API.

There is another way to do it? maybe with another API, service or client library? or even paying a little more.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official Bing text to speech API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput)

> The maximum size of the SSML input that is supported is **1,024** characters, including all tags.